# How can I click on a button "onclick" .. using xml

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I was trying to click a button to "sign in" in a website using xml

But the problem I found was that, I couldn't click that button .. it seems that it is not a button and has no link .. how can I click that button in order to sign in using xml

here is the code I tried to use

```
Sub signinXML()


     Dim request As Object
     Dim response As String
     Dim html As New HTMLDocument
     Dim htmlsignins As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
     Dim htmlsignin As MSHTML.IHTMLElement


     Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")


     request.Open "GET", "https://www.investing.com", False


     request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

     request.send


     response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

     html.body.innerHTML = response



     Set htmlsignins = html.getElementsByClassName("topBarText")


    For Each htmlsignin In htmlsignins
       'Debug.Print htmlsignin.innerText
        
     If htmlsignin.getAttribute("innertext") = "Sign In" Then
        htmlsignin.Click
        Debug.Print htmlsignin.getAttribute("innertext")
        Exit For
        Else: MsgBox "not found"
     End If
      
    Next htmlsignin


   End Sub
```

here is the HTML snippet

```html
<a onclick="overlay.overlayLogin();" href="javascript:void(0);" class="login bold">Sign In</a>
```

Comment: `If htmlsignin.getAttribute("innertext") = "Sign In/Free Sign Up" Then`

Comment: doesn't work ..I want to sign in .. but I can't do that without clicking that button